# Always the smallest picture from srcset is chosen

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design, width, filesize

We had an approach to use the srcset attribute to provide not only a different resolution but also a different image section within a responsive design. The alternative image url was associated with "320w" in order to show only on smartphones in portrait mode.

Since Chrome is now supporting srcset it turns out that the browser always chooses the small image regardless of the actual viewport, probably due to its lower filesize. Does that mean we have to resort to other attributes and javascript again?

Comment: Ok, just read that only Pixel density, not viewport width is yet supported in Chrome.

Comment: I've start using it already anyway. I'm also looking forward to browser choosing image depending on network speed. It's kind of stupid to always load the biggest images on mobile devices.